# Use or not leading slash in value for @RequestMapping. Need official docs or point to Spring source?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I involved in project where I found a mix of:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "events/...");
@RequestMapping(value = "/events/...");
```

(with and without slash before method level annotation).

I perform search:

```
site:http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x  slash
```

and read these links:

- http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?130753-Various-Spring-MVC-RequestMapping-configuration-questions
- [Various Spring MVC RequestMapping configuration questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12712232/various-spring-mvc-requestmapping-configuration-questions)
- [Handling of pre-slash in @RequestMapping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6984474/handling-of-pre-slash-in-requestmapping)
- https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6570

But none of these sources answer why skipping slash allowed. Official Spring docs always shown examples with slashes...

Need point to official docs or to Spring sources.

Answer (score 67, accepted):

It does not matter: If the path does not start with an `/` then Spring (DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping) will add it.

See method `String[] determineUrlsForHandler(String beanName)` of Class `DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping` line 122 (Spring 3.1.2) (that is for the class level)

```
String[] methodLevelPatterns = determineUrlsForHandlerMethods(handlerType, true);
for (String typeLevelPattern : typeLevelPatterns) {
    if (!typeLevelPattern.startsWith("/")) {
            typeLevelPattern = "/" + typeLevelPattern;
    }
```

See method `String[] determineUrlsForHandler(Class<?> handlerType, final boolean hasTypeLevelMapping))` of Class `DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping` line 182 (Spring 3.1.2) (that is for the method level)

```
String[] mappedPatterns = mapping.value();
if (mappedPatterns.length > 0) {
for (String mappedPattern : mappedPatterns) {
    if (!hasTypeLevelMapping && !mappedPattern.startsWith("/")) {
        mappedPattern = "/" + mappedPattern;
    }
```