# Url path of mapping in controller

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-restcontroller

In the url of Mapping like

```
@GetMapping,
```

is there any difference between

```
@GetMapping("/users")
```

and
    @GetMapping("users")

Answer (score 1):

Actually NO.

If the path does not start with an `/` then Spring (DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping) will add it.

See the below method `String[] determineUrlsForHandler(String beanName)` of Class `DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping`.

```
String[] methodLevelPatterns = determineUrlsForHandlerMethods(handlerType, true);
for (String typeLevelPattern : typeLevelPatterns) {
    if (!typeLevelPattern.startsWith("/")) {
            typeLevelPattern = "/" + typeLevelPattern;
    }
```

See this [use-or-not-leading-slash-in-value-for-requestmapping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12742695/use-or-not-leading-slash-in-value-for-requestmapping-need-official-docs-or-poi)