# Getting error while submitting the form as post method not supported

Tags: spring-mvc, sap-commerce-cloud

```
@RequestMapping(value = FILE_UPLOAD, method = RequestMethod.POST)

@RequireHardLogIn
public ResponseEntity<String> uploadFileHandler(final Model model, @ModelAttribute("importCSVSavedCartForm")
final ImportCSVSavedCartForm importCSVSavedCartForm, final BindingResult bindingResult)

{

    customFileValidator.validate(importCSVSavedCartForm, bindingResult);


    if (bindingResult.hasErrors())
    {
        final String errorMessage = getMessageSource().getMessage(bindingResult.getAllErrors().get(0).getCode(), null,
                getI18nService().getCurrentLocale());
        return new ResponseEntity<String>(errorMessage, HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
    }
```

Comment: try this @PostMapping("/File_UPLOAD")

Comment: @NafazBenzema - It doesn't matter with [Spring MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12742695/use-or-not-leading-slash-in-value-for-requestmapping-need-official-docs-or-poi).

Comment: @ArvindKumarAvanish yes, I thought that. but his question is not clear

Comment: As you are returning a body you must add the annotation `@ResponseBody`. What is your postman/curl call that you are using to hit this method?