# spring boot mapping without slash

Tags: spring-boot, rest, request-mapping, get-mapping

I'm having a controller mapping as shown below

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/v1/connector")
public class Controller
```

and the API mapping as below

```
@GetMapping("2/auth")
```

when I hit the URL it's giving me the response as request URL not found.
Can anyone tell why I'm getting this?

Comment: You are missing `@RestController` annotation along with @RequestMapping. Also, check the REST API url naming conventions , not sure `2/auth` is a good definition ! Also ensure, that this Controller class is in the same package as `Main` class (Which has `@SpringBootAnnotation` !

Comment: @Harsh "@RestController" is there, also edited the question, "2/auth" is actually my question, can we write like that?

Comment: Ideally, REST API definitions are descriptive verbs , numbers represent value which could be path or query parameters, I suggest you read this https://restfulapi.net/resource-naming/  & https://nordicapis.com/10-best-practices-for-naming-api-endpoints/

Answer (score 3):

`@GetMapping` is a composed annotation that acts as a shortcut for `@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod. GET)`.

`@RequestMapping` maps HTTP requests to handler methods of MVC and REST controllers.

When you use a base path on your controller class, all controllers in that class accept URL paths that start with your given base path. In your case:

```java
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/v1/connector")
public class Controller {
...
}
```

This means all of the controllers inside this class have the base path of `/v1/connector` and this means is a constant part of your URL and cant be changed.

So when you declare a `@GetMapping("2/auth")`, Spring will automatically add a `/` at the beginning of your path if there was no `/`. And your path will be `http://YOUR-HOST-NAME/v1/connector/2/auth` instead of `http://YOUR-HOST-NAME/v1/connector2/auth`.

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12744010/11121568) for more clarification.

So If your application has paths like `/v1/connector1`, `/v1/connector2`, `/v1/connector3`, etc. It means the `connector{n}` is not constant and you must declare it on each of your controllers' methods separately.

```java
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/v1")
public class Controller {

    @GetMapping("/connector2/auth")
    ...

    @GetMapping("/connector3/auth")
    ...

    .
    .
    .
}
```

Comment: The rest controller annotation is there, also edited the question, The issue is I'm hitting "/v1/connector2/auth" but still getting the "request URL not found"

Comment: Ok, I checked it now, and it seems spring will automatically add a slash at the beginning of `RequestMapping` if there was no slash existing. I'll update my answer. But in your case, why you don't do it this way? If `connector` is not a static path, consider extracting it from the class `@RequestMapping` annotation and declare it for each method.